# Grunt themes.js file overwritten when running composer install

Tags: magento2, less, magento2.1.5, grunt

When running the *composer install* command the www/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js file is being overwritten and removing the config for my custom theme. When searching online I came across the following GitHub issue:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7196

See below the changes I tried based on the issue above:

1. Copy www/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js to www/dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js and specify the custom theme as so:

`module.exports = {
        custom_theme: {
            area: 'frontend',
            name: 'Custom/theme',
            locale: 'en_GB',
            files: [
                'css/styles-m',
                'css/styles-l',
                'css/petlandia',
                'css/email',
                'css/email-inline'
            ],
            dsl: 'less'
        },
    }`

2. Rename grunt-config.json.sample -> grunt-config.json.

This method so far hasn't worked and the custom theme can not be found when running *grunt exec:custom_theme*. Is there anyway I can extend the themes.js file so that when running *composer install* or *composer update* my custom theme config is not removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Gruntfile.js.sample and grunt-config.js.sample from the [repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2) and run

```
cp Gruntfile.js{.sample,}
cp grunt-config.js{.sample,}
```

That takes care of actually loading your renamed themes configuration.